# WebView crops stream after resize

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, resize, android-webview

I have a webView inside a collapsingToolBarLayout. I use the OnOffsetChangedListener callback provided by the AppBarLayout to adjust the size of the webView (i insert layoutParams inside webView) dynamically as the user scrolls down/up. What I observe is that the stream crops itself once I start decreasing the webView size and it shows only a part of the stream. Once I scroll up the stream shows fine.

I have included in my webview setup some solutions i have found on other questions like:

```
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

but they didn't have an effect.

I want to point out that this callback (OnOffsetChangedListener) is being called repeatedly even when the user doesn't scroll (because of UI updates), so my webview setup is being called multiple times. I am not sure why this is happening, is there any way to achieve this?

**INSIDE onOffsetChangedListener**:

My webView setUp method:

```
var settings: WebSettings? = webView?.getSettings()
        //WebSettings settings = streamHolder.getSettings();
        settings?.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
        settings?.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
        settings?.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)
        settings?.setAllowFileAccess(true)
        settings?.useWideViewPort = true
        settings?.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true)
        settings?.setDomStorageEnabled(true)
        settings?.setDatabaseEnabled(true)

        //settings?.setSupportZoom(true)
        webView?.setWebViewClient(object: BaseWebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                //view?.zoomOut()
            }
        })
```

and inside load url method:

```
if (webView?.url.equals(url))
            return
if (url != null) {
      mWebViewStream?.loadUrl(url)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about steam, is this a video you trying to scale to fill the screen? (maybe sharing screenshot make it easier to understand)

Comment: it is a streaming video, coming from a live url, i cannot share a screenshot, if you need more specifics i can try to get them but i was thinking that these would suffice